# How to get different map in card view for each nearby restaurant

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

What is missing in my code as i am unable to show nearby restaurants in each of my card view in Recyclerview. I am getting all places in single view i need to get different map in card view for each nearby restaurant.I have used retrofit for getting data from api

**Adapter class**

```
public class ListMapAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListMapAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Context mCtx;
private List<Result> mapList;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public ListMapAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Result> mapList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.mapList = mapList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Result mapData = mapList.get(position);
    mapList.set(position, mapData);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mapList.size();
}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mCtx)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            })
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)

            .build();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    MapView map;
    CardView card;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        map = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mapList);
        card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
        if (map != null) {
            map.onCreate(null);
            map.onResume();
            map.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(itemView.getContext());
        mMap = googleMap;


        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mCtx,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        build_retrofit_and_get_response("restaurant");
    }

    private void build_retrofit_and_get_response(String type) {
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/";

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitMaps service = retrofit.create(RetrofitMaps.class);

        Call<Example> call = service.getNearbyPlaces(type, latitude + "," + longitude, PROXIMITY_RADIUS);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                try {
                    mMap.clear();
                    // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {
                        Double lat = response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
                        Double lng = response.body().getResults().get(i).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();
                        String placeName = response.body().getResults().get(i).getName();
                        String vicinity = response.body().getResults().get(i).getVicinity();
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        // Position of Marker on Map
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        // Adding Title to the Marker
                        markerOptions.title(placeName + " : " + vicinity);
                        // Adding Marker to the Camera.
                        Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        // Adding colour to the marker
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                        // move map camera
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

**Main List Activity**

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.rvListMap)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Result> productList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvListMap);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListMapAdapter adapter = new ListMapAdapter(this, productList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

**Retrofit interface**

```
public interface RetrofitMaps {
    /*
   * Retrofit get annotation with our URL
   * And our method that will return us details of student.
   */
    @GET("api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDN7RJFmImYAca96elyZlE5s_fhX-MMuhk")
    Call<Example> getNearbyPlaces(@Query("type") String type, @Query("location") String location, @Query("radius") int radius);
}
```

**POJO**

public class Result {

```
@SerializedName("geometry")
@Expose
private Geometry geometry;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("opening_hours")
@Expose
private OpeningHours openingHours;
@SerializedName("photos")
@Expose
private List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
@SerializedName("place_id")
@Expose
private String placeId;
@SerializedName("rating")
@Expose
private Double rating;
@SerializedName("reference")
@Expose
private String reference;
@SerializedName("scope")
@Expose
private String scope;
@SerializedName("types")
@Expose
private List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("vicinity")
@Expose
private String vicinity;
@SerializedName("price_level")
@Expose
private Integer priceLevel;

/**
 * @return The geometry
 */
public Geometry getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
}

/**
 * @param geometry The geometry
 */
public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
}

/**
 * @return The icon
 */
public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

/**
 * @param icon The icon
 */
public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

/**
 * @return The id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id The id
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return The openingHours
 */
public OpeningHours getOpeningHours() {
    return openingHours;
}

/**
 * @param openingHours The opening_hours
 */
public void setOpeningHours(OpeningHours openingHours) {
    this.openingHours = openingHours;
}

/**
 * @return The photos
 */
public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
    return photos;
}

/**
 * @param photos The photos
 */
public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
    this.photos = photos;
}

/**
 * @return The placeId
 */
public String getPlaceId() {
    return placeId;
}

/**
 * @param placeId The place_id
 */
public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
    this.placeId = placeId;
}

/**
 * @return The rating
 */
public Double getRating() {
    return rating;
}

/**
 * @param rating The rating
 */
public void setRating(Double rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

/**
 * @return The reference
 */
public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

/**
 * @param reference The reference
 */
public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

/**
 * @return The scope
 */
public String getScope() {
    return scope;
}

/**
 * @param scope The scope
 */
public void setScope(String scope) {
    this.scope = scope;
}

/**
 * @return The types
 */
public List<String> getTypes() {
    return types;
}

/**
 * @param types The types
 */
public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
    this.types = types;
}

/**
 * @return The vicinity
 */
public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

/**
 * @param vicinity The vicinity
 */
public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
}

/**
 * @return The priceLevel
 */
public Integer getPriceLevel() {
    return priceLevel;
}

/**
 * @param priceLevel The price_level
 */
public void setPriceLevel(Integer priceLevel) {
    this.priceLevel = priceLevel;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is the api to fetch result of nearby places using google places api.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=22.4892,72.7996&radius=500&types=food&key=<your places api key>
```

You need to provide lattitude and longitude of the place from where you want ot get nearby places, Also you need to provide type of places like food, hospital,school,etc.

Here is the list of supported types:

[Types supported in place search and addition](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

**Edit**

Here is the json you will get.

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"results": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
            "lat": 22.4909137,
            "lng": 72.799812
            },
            "viewport": {}      
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
        "id": "f5472c3bf89ee78bf6afaf46510eaff1b2276481",
        "name": "Dolly Studio",
        "place_id": "ChIJ4-N6Z35UXjkRele_KJ8p24w",
        "reference": "CmRSAAAAGDR9Rp83US-bOIYdqRVTf..........",
        "scope": "GOOGLE",
        "types": [
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "store",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
        ],
    "vicinity": "Petlad - Sunav Road, Aaradhna Society, Rangaipura, Petlad"
    }
],
"status": "OK"
}
```

Fetch the "results" array and loop over it to get single values of places.
For every place fetch "geometry" object and get 'lat' and 'lng' values.
And if you want get place name also.
By lat and lng values you can show the place in map. And that is the thing you want.

**Second Edit**

```
private void build_retrofit_and_get_response(String type) {
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/";

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitMaps service = retrofit.create(RetrofitMaps.class);

    Call<Example> call = service.getNearbyPlaces(type, latitude + "," + longitude, PROXIMITY_RADIUS);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

            try {
                mMap.clear();
                // This loop will go through all the results and add marker on each location.
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().size(); i++) {

                    Result result= new Result(); //create a result object for a single cardview item

                    //add everthing you need in one cardview to this result object

                    productList.add(result); // add this single card item to your productlist
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify adapter that item is added

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

What you are doing is setting everything up in adapter class. And also in your main activity just defining the productlist. That is why it is giving you only one item. Migrate this retrofit method and all its related methods to mainActivity and refer my last update. You need to create new result object everytime you want to add a new item and add it to the list.

All data setting up operations are need to be in the activity not in the adapter class. That is the point you were wrong.

Comment: I know the api i want to know how to show each nearby restaurant in card view

Comment: Updated the answer, do check it.

Comment: will it show in list form in cardview?As i have already tried looping as shown above

Comment: If you already get the desired list then what is the problem in displaying.? Are you using any recyclerview or any custom listview?

Comment: If you are not using any list view or recyclerview then how would the data itself get displayed in any form? You sound like you are new in android. Refer any tutorial first to implement a listview or recyclerview.

Comment: yes i am new and i have used recyclerview and a layout for its display with cardview but just dont know how to set it.i am only getting in single card

Comment: Refer this tutorial. https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: Updated the answer.